# Hash table complexity?

Tags: hash, hashtable, time-complexity

Say there is hash table with 'n' entries and let 'h' be a randomized hash function. What is the worst case time complexity of inserting m keys into this hash table using h. The keys are drawn from a universal set 'U' where absoulte value of U >= mn.

My best guess would be O(n). Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you take the absolute value of a set? Do you mean the absolute value of each element in the set >= mn, or perhaps the sum / product of all elements in the set?

Comment: Each individual element.

Comment: I suspect the problem is underspecified because, as far as I can tell, the absolute value constraint plays no role, and it's a somewhat strange constraint to give if it's not going to matter, unless it was just given to mislead.

Comment: Most licekly to mislead.

Comment: (I think the "absolute value" being talked about is set cardinality, by the way). What kind of hash table is this? Linear probing? Chaining? Something else?